# LINQ or lambda expression with subquery and NOT IN logic

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to wrap my head around the proper syntax for a LINQ query **or** a lambda expression that returns the equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tool t 
WHERE t.UniqTool 
  NOT IN (SELECT t1.uniqtool  
          FROM tool t1
          INNER JOIN [version] v ON v.UniqTool = t1.UniqTool 
            AND v.IsBetaVersion = 1)
```

Basically, I want to get the list of tools that don't already have a beta version. I have a tool object that has both the UniqTool (ID value) and a boolean property indicating whether that version is beta.

Here was my initial attempt:

```
var tools = from t in session.CachedTools where !t.IsBetaVersion select t;
```

I realized it gave me the wrong result set and I got lost trying to figure out the subquery with NOT IN logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a navigation property on your `Tool` entity this query should get you all the tools that do not have any version that is a beta:

```
var tools = session.CachedTools.Where(t => !t.Versions.Any(v => v.IsBetaVersion == 1));
```